# Failed to attach all styles, scripts etc, Router and .htaccess

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, scripting, load

So I've been working on Router and links like

```
localhost/main
```

works just fine, it loads what it should but everytime I add something new like

```
localhost/main/bla/bla/bla
```

it still loads the page, but can not load the styles, scripts etc, even than .htaccess heads everything to index.php, I am using

> $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

any suggestions?